# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery 1.7 and  I am using a number which is 28 digits long. I get this error thrown

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null    in jquery-1.7.1.min.js:2
```

I am Chrome browser. What is the limit for a number type in Javascript?

Code:

```
var rules = [];
rules.push({ field:"FieldName","op":"gt","data":"2525252525252525252525252525"});
```

Comment: you object is null, so it cant find length of that.

Comment: In javascript you can't use .length on a number. Could you provide the code that is creating the error?

Comment: Thanks folks..I found the underlying cause. As the data was null from the result set I was using $.each on the data and this was causing it to fail.

Comment: TIP : wrap `field` with `"`